# Output blob path "$web/index.html" considered as invalid for Functions App

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

Azure Blob storage supports a "static web" feature through a forced container name, "$web".

When building a functions app, if you want to save what your function generated inside a blob document, you need to specify a path, but a path with the container name "$web" is considered as invalid.

I'm using Azure functions runtime ~2 using Javascript as language.

The `function.json` file is shown below.

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myTimer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "0 0 5 * * *"
    },
    {
      "type": "blob",
      "name": "$return",
      "path": "$web/index.html",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'd expect the output to generate and save the file to the blob path `$web/index.html`, but I obtain the following error.

```
Validation failed for property 'BlobPath', value '$web/index.html'. The field BlobPath is invalid.
```

Comment: Right now, as the code's fairly big, it'd require quite some work, so I'd rather try to find a solution in javascript first, before re-working the code in C# if nothing else's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the standard Azure functions output pipe, I used the [Azure node SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node).

I promisified the upload method (which uses callbacks in the V2 SDK).

```js
function upload(svc, container, blob, content) {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => svc.createBlockBlobFromText(container, blob, content, (err, resp, _) => {
        if (err) {
            rej(err);
        }

        res(resp);
    }));
}
```

I then used it to upload my generated file.

```js
const blobSvc = createBlobService();
await upload(blobSvc, process.env.OUTPUT_CONTAINER, process.env.OUTPUT_BLOB, render(readFileSync('D:/home/site/wwwroot/TimerTrigger1/template.html', 'utf-8'), { user, photos }));
```